# specifying the "request method" in externalinterface.call method?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe

When the user try to download the file ,i need to open a new html window and download the file , currently iam using "ExternalInterface.call" but i need to set the "requestmethod" otherwise server is throwing the error ,how to specify "requestmethod"?

Comment: ExternalInterface.call can call JS functions, so get the JS function to set the request method and the URL

Comment: I am able to set the URL, how to set the request method in JavaScript

Comment: thats outside my area of expertise

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the global `navigateToURL` method? You can pass in a `URLRequest` object which has a property called `method` and will solve your problem.

So you need something like this:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; // or anything you want

// parameters can be added to a URLVariables object 
// which then can be set as requests data property
// example:

var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
params.username = "test";
params.password = "123";

request.data = params;

// load the page
// specify '_blank' parameter to open it in a new browser window
navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
```

Comment: navigateToURL has some problems with the chrome 29. that is the reason we are looking for other solution.

Comment: Then do as @Lee Burrows suggested.